# How to create an interface with optional values

Tags: typescript

I have an object for which at the start I don't know what keys are going to be in it, but it seems that typescript seems to not consider the possibility that a value for a key might not exist:

```
interface ById {
    [key:string]: number[]
}

const test: ById = {
    dummyValue: [1,2,3]
}

const doThing = (key: string) => {
    // regardless of if this key exists, it still assumes it's an array
    test[key].push(4)
}

doThing('test')
```

I figured I'd make an interface that makes it explicit that the value for this item might be undefined, so that it shows an error if I don't check if it exists, but for some reason **it shows me an error, even though I check**.

```
interface ByIdOptional {
    [key:string]: number[] | undefined
}

const test: ByIdOptional = {
    dummyValue: [1,2,3]
}

const doThing = (key: string) => {
    if (typeof test[key] !== 'undefined') {
        // Even though I'm testing for undefined, it's showing an error here
        test[key].push(4)
    }
}

doThing('test')
```

Is there a better way of achieving this, and to get type safety code that uses this object? I've added [the code to a Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=16#code/PTAEElQdwQwOwC6gQe1AWxgawKagJZI4AeADgDb4DGhyAFjEigEYBWOVCAzqDACZ0cAJ3xwA5sjQI6+HqITCAZjCo4AUCAz4xdJHBRIY5WAE8eDAG54YoC0YCueRSiGhcZ0MxyiJ5FClw+UHtSAjgCBAAaUEE4VVANMGk8AAN7OD4cRVEcPhS1eSUVPAAhE3A+AHlSBHwUOCNQAG81UDbQAG13AC4uBBFxAF1u0Dh7dC8hDsHQAB9gjKycvjUAXzU1Knq+5Bw+kbKK6tr6xoBeZtb2vnH0EwA1BxwRjoBGSIAmSIBmQbWNrZwHZ8FAAFRk4lAFwAFD1QH0BmIAJRQgB8l3aBEUoGhCBMpBwKGxCj6XRwJhmAEIzhcAOTpTLZOC5WkolqYzGaACiVnC0hQ9h0EFp6F2fR8oGcrgZS2ZfGihFpPC4dBQUAl8FAwiELhiwnUHPaJIQZIpADpSPYVdCACxIq5tdbrNQg8E+aG042soA) as well (for testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `test[key]` to a local. TypeScript will then refine the type of the local based on the guard:

```
interface ByIdOptional {
    [key:string]: number[] | undefined
}

const test: ByIdOptional = {
    dummyValue: [1,2,3]
}

const doThing = (key: string) => {
    const array = test[key]
    if (typeof array !== 'undefined') {
        array.push(4)  // <=================== No error here
    }
}

doThing('test')
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=16#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIE8CSATA8gBzGAHsQ4AbZAbwChl7kBtAawnQC4BnMKUAcwC67ZCACuAWwBG0RgOQAfZKJDYIMUBGw0AvjRoJS3ZJG7CMOAkVIVkAXmp0G2CePQA1CqIjDGARgA0AEz+AMwCOnoGIEbYxAAqABb8dsgAFKwcyNy8IHwAlHYAfA4MyFFGcFBQcOgpJmAsbAIA3I70wDBpYOj4EMSdldW1AIS29gDkyqrqIJrjBbSlpYM1AHT4opwJqQAseW3Iuro0sYn8qeP180A)

Comment: That works. I do feel it's not always the neatest solution to create locals (especially if you only use them once or twice), but it fixes the issue anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `| undefined` for the index signature value type is a good idea; right now index signature types are implausibly assumed to have defined values at each key.  It's more correct but potentially annoying for the compiler to always expect a possibly-`undefined` value in an index signature.  There's an open GitHub issue tracking this ([microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778)) but I wouldn't expect any change here soon.

The problem with your check is that the compiler doesn't really have a way to track the sort of narrowing implied by `typeof test[key] !== 'undefined'`.  The variable `key` is only known to be of type `string`.  The only possible narrowing the compiler could do would be to say "all `string`-valued keys of `test` have been verified not to be `undefined`".  That's not a desirable narrowing, so the compiler basically does nothing.  There's a GitHub issue file about this, ([microsoft/TypeScript#31445](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31445)), which was closed as a design limitation.  To address it the language would have to keep track of which individual variables were used as keys in type guards, which would be a lot of extra work for the occasional help it would provide.

The easiest workaround here is just to copy the value in question to a new variable, which can be checked via control flow analysis without worrying about re-doing property accesses:

```
const doThing = (key: string) => {
    const testKey = test[key];
    if (typeof testKey !== 'undefined') {
        testKey.push(4)
    }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIE8CSATA8gBzGAHsQ4AbZAbwChl7kBtAawnQC4BnMKUAcwC67ZCACuAWwBG0RgOQAfZKJDYIMUBGw0AvjRoJS3ZJG7CMOAkVIVkAXmp0G2CePQA1CqIjDGARgA0AEz+AMwCOsh6BiBG2MQAKgAW-HbIABSsHMjcvCB8AJR2AHwODMjRRiZgANJsqVUsbAIA3I70wDDpYOj4EMSdVbXoyACEtvYA5Mqq6iCaE4W0ZWWDbAB0+KKciWkALPltyLq6NHFJ-GkTVQtAA)

Comment: I figured that was why. :-)